# Prove that there exists $m>0$ such $(m+1)g(x)\leq f(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are two continuous function on $[a,b]$ such that $0<g(x)<f(x)$ for all $x\in [a,b]$.

Proof that:
There exists $m>0$ such that for all $x$ on $[a,b]$, we have $(m+1)g(x)\leq f(x)$.

I tried to use IVT but it doesn't work.

Comment: $f$ and $g$ are continuous on a compact set and hence...

Comment: It sounds like you can use extreme value theorem here

Comment: How i can use it here i think it should be done by contradiction

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $f-g$ is still continuous on the mentioned closed interval, thus this function ($f-g$) attains max value and min value.

Also since $f-g>0$ for all relevant $x$ the minimum value of $f-g$, say $E$ exists and is strictly positive. Similarly, as $g$ is positive, the maximum value of $g$, say $F$ exists and is strictly positive. Given so, there must exists some $m>0$ such that $mF\leq E$. See if you can finish it off.

----edit----

So I am guessing you could accept the above statements and so I shall continuous.

For all relevant $x$ you have $mg(x)\leq f(x)-g(x)$ using definition of max/min. Rearrange it gives you the required inequality.

Comment: Can you continue your proof because i still get no idea

Comment: @MalikaAAli Alright I have finished it off.

Comment: Thanks now i understand it

Comment: @MalikaAAli no worries bro

Answer (score 0):

$(1)$ Choose any $x_0$ such that $g(x_0)<f(x_0)$
$(2)$ Since $g(x)<f(x)$ for all $x$ on $[a,b]$, we have
$$\int_a^b f(x)-g(x) dx \geq \int_{x_0}^b f(x)-g(x) dx $$
$(3)$ Since $f$ and $g$ are continuous, we have
$$\int_{x_0}^b f(x)-g(x) dx \geq \int_{x_0}^b (f(x_0)-g(x_0)) dx = (f(x_0)-g(x_0))(b-x_0) $$
$(4)$ Hence
$(b-x_0)\int_a^b f(x)-g(x) dx \geq (f(x_0)-g(x_0))(b-x_0) $
$(5)$ Since $\int_a^b f(x)-g(x) dx >0$, we have
$(b-x_0)>0$
$(6)$ Hence from
$(5)$, we obtain
$$\int_a^b f(x)-g(x) dx \geq \frac{(f(x_0)-g(x_0))(b-x_0)}{b-x_0} = f(x_0)-g(x_0) $$
$(7)$ Let $m=f(x_0)-g(x_0)$
$(8)$ Since $g(x)<f(x)$ for all $x$ on $[a,b]$, we have
$g(x)<f(x)-m$ for all $x$ on $[a,b]$
$(9)$ Hence
$(m+1)g(x)<(m+1)(f(x)-m)$ for all $x$ on $[a,b]$
$(10)$ Hence $(m+1)g(x)<f(x)$ for all $x$ on $[a,b]$

Comment: You have over killing it but thanks for the participation